# Possibility of time-stamps in .xsession-errors file?

Tags: debian, xorg, x-server

Is there possibility of having time-stamps in the .xsession-errors file as errors are logged but time-stamps are unfortunately not there. If anybody knows of any move towards it, would be nice to know. Also if such a feature-request were to be asked, where should one file it upstream, at x.org or somewhere else ?

Comment: What value would timestamps add? What can you not do because the current entries lack timestamps? You would break my `.xsession-errors` analysis tools.

Comment: fwiw, on modern setups that use `systemd` [everything logs to `journal`](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Desktop_Migration_and_Administration_Guide/user-sessions.html#session-logs)  where you have timestamps and what not;  `.xsession-errors` doesn't even exist anymore.

Answer (score 7):

`/etc/X11/Xsession` redirects the standard output and standard error streams of your whole X session directly into `.xsession-errors` by the equivalent of

```
exec >>.xsession-errors 2>&1
```

then proceeds with starting your session. The last step of that is executing your `.xsession` if you have one. Install the *devscripts* package to get `annotate-output`, then create a `.xsession` like

```
#!/bin/sh
annotate-output x-session-manager
```

(use whatever fits you in place of `x-session-manager`). Make this script executable, and restart your X session.

Comment: Would there be a way to let this script automatically each time you eneter the X session ???

Comment: @shirish This answer describes a permanent solution. It effects all further X sessions until the whole startup mechanism is replaced by some large scale change in your setup.

Comment: FTR, I had to remove the "wait" call at the end of `annotate-output` to make the logout function work correctly (at least with MATE 1.20)

Comment: @Joril did you report the bug to the Mate maintainers ???

Comment: @shirish I'm not sure this is a problem with Mate itself...? *wondering* Anyway I should at least test with the latest Mate version, first ^__^;

Comment: Will do, thank you.